# What is the maximum length for a key in a map in Apex?

Tags: apex, map

Is there a limit to the maximum key size for a map in Apex?

Say if I have `Map<String, SObject>`, how long can the string `key` be?

Comment: I suspect the answer is "practically no limit" and "the ultimate determining factor is the size of the heap"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy enough to test.

```java
Map<String, Integer> testMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
// a string 5.5 million characters long
String testKey = 'a'.repeat(5500000);
testMap.put(testKey, 1);
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
System.debug(testMap.get(testKey)); // prints 1
```

The above works just fine.

You could take this particular example to about 5.99 million characters (you need to reserve some heap space for the map, the value you store in the map, etc...), and after that you run into the heap limit.

Comment: I did some tests but couldn't get a definite answer. This is great, thank you!

Comment: You forgot about asynchronous limits...

Answer (score 4):

The maximum length is actually `Limits.getLimitHeapSize()`. That's because the maximum length of a string is limited to this value. You can temporarily exceed this limit across multiple objects, but doing this in a single string is not allowed; you'd get a String exception with the message stating that the string is too long.